# Find the intersection points of all circles

Tags: r, algorithm

Given a set of 2D coordinates and radius for each coordinate how to efficiently find all the points where at least 2 circles of the set of circles intersect?

I understand two circles intersect at a maximum of 2 points so it can be done by pairwise comparisons between two circles and looping over the entire data set but when the real data set has 10000 circles, doing all the pairwise comparisons will be computationally expensive.

Below is the sample code for generating Test Data.

```
    library("plotrix")
    set.seed(1995)
    XCoordinate = sample(x = 1:100,size = 20)
    set.seed(2000)
    YCoordinate = sample(x = 1:100,size = 20)
    set.seed(1997)
    Radius = sample(x = 1:50,size = 20)
    ## Create DataFrame
    TestData = data.frame(XCoordinate = XCoordinate,YCoordinate = YCoordinate, 
    Radius = Radius )

    ## Plot Circle
    plot(TestData$XCoordinate, TestData$YCoordinate, 
         type="n", xlab="", ylab="" , main="Test draw.circle")

    for(Row in 1:nrow(TestData)){
      PlotCircle(TestData$XCoordinate[Row], 
                 TestData$YCoordinate[Row], 
                 TestData$Radius[Row])
    }
```

I am trying find all the points that are marked in black in the attached.

[image: Small example]

Comment: It is not clear where exactly is your problem. You can build the 2 intersection points of the first 2 circles and then for each of them check if the point lies on all the circles. Then you'll have 0,1 or 2 answers.

Comment: Probably the way I framed the question is confusing. I am trying to get all the points where at least two circles intersect. I'll re frame the question with an image.

Comment: Write a function that takes in two circles as input and outputs the intersection points. Then write a for loop that goes over all pairs of your circles.

Comment: I am trying to implement the strategy you have just mentioned  but curious if there is a way to optimize it. I have a 10000 points and I think it will be computationally expensive doing pairwise comparisons to get the intersected points

Comment: I have 10000 circles not really sure about the number of  intersection points. Probably I have to write one more function to get the count and even that takes 1000C2 comparisons.

Comment: If you want all the intersections, there's no way around pairwise comparisons. If you don't compare two circles, you have no way to know whether they intersect or not. That said, `choose(10000, 2)` is close to 50M comparisons, so you're right to be concerned. You could start with the `dist` function on the {x,y} coords, the meat of which is written in C. The resulting distance matrix is at least half of the work you need to do, and will let you tell quickly if two circles intersect.

Comment: For so many (small?) objects, spatial hashing could be an option (see e.g. https://conkerjo.wordpress.com/2009/06/13/spatial-hashing-implementation-for-fast-2d-collisions/ ). I'm not sure whether there is an R-library for that, but it should not be toooo hard to implement in any language.

Answer (score 2):

You may get quite a few false positive candidates but unless the circles are pretty much laid out on top of each other, we could significantly reduce the number of pair checks by calculating the bounding boxes for the circles and running a line sweep. Intersecting circles imply bounding box intersection, although not vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Probably more complicated to implement but maybe more selective than the solution of גלעד ברקן:

1. Build an [R-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree), organizing the circle centers and add an
   additional attribute `maxRadius` to each node that holds the maximum
   radius of any circle who's center is contained in that node
2. For each circle `c`, find candidate circles performing range search on
   the R-Tree. Discard nodes `p` when `minDist(c, p) > c.radius + p.maxRadius`
3. Compute intersections for each candidate

Building the R-Tree in 2D is generally O(n log n), range search is considered O(log n) for moderate ranges (radii). Which makes a total of **O(n log n)** in the average case.

Comment: Wouldn't this allow for false positives when circles are contained in other circles? (Could be O(n^2) with degenerate data? e.g., `(  ( (()))))`)

Comment: Since all candidates have to be verified via step 3 there shouldn't be false positives, or did I miss a case? The first two steps are only for candidate generation, much like your proposed algorithm. Good point on circles in circles, this case is not handled efficiently

Comment: I meant false positive candidates.

Comment: hmm, when a circle falls inside an r-Tree node then minDist(c, p) = 0, thus the node would not be discarded. When you are at leaf level, you compute intersections with all circles in the leaf node (probably that part is unclear in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented the sweep-line algorithm for circle intersection in C++ here:
github.com/malyasova/intersect_circles

It works like the [segment intersection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm) only the upper and lower arc of each circle are inserted into status instead of segments. It works in O((n+k)log n) time, where n is the number of circles and k is the number of intersections.